# Finite current in equilibrium in tilted Dirac Spectrum

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am calculting current for Dirac semimetal with energy dispersion

$\varepsilon(s,p)= v_{T}^{x}p_{x}+sv_{F}|p|.$ 
Here $s=\pm$ refers to conduction and valence bands. The velocity for above spectrum in x direction is, 
    $v_{x}=v_{T}^{x}+sv_{F}\cos\phi\sin\theta.$
But the first term on velocity makes the current non-zero even in equilibrium. Although second term is right and do get cancelled in equilibrium.
   $j_{x}=\sum_{s=\pm}\int dp p^{2}\int d\phi d\theta \sin\theta v_{x} f_{eq}(\varepsilon(s,p))=v_{T}^{x}\sum_{s=\pm}\int dp p^{2}\int d\phi d\theta \sin\theta f_{eq}.$
This is not zero in equilibrium. But this is clearly contradictory to what one observe in real sample. Because Dirac semimetals do not pass current unless a voltage source is applied. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your integration boundaries, i.e. the first Brillouin-Zone? You are in 3d, right? Where is the radial part of the integral?

Comment: Further, for calculations of dirac particles you should use the dirac notation. Can you write down the Dirac-Hamiltonian for the given system?

Comment: @ denklo, Yes, i can write the Dirac Hamiltonian, $$H = v_{T}^{x}p_{x}+\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}$$. The boundaries of the theta integral is 0 to $\pi$, while the boundaries of the $\phi$ integral is 0 to 2$\pi$, and boundary of the momentum radial part is from 0 to $\infty$.

Comment: @ denklo, i have added the radial part of the momentum integral.

Comment: @denklo, i have tried your suggestion of using Dirac notation or approach of current, $\frac{\partial \psi^{\dagger} \psi}{\partial t}= \frac{1}{i\hbar}(\psi^{\dagger}H\psi-\psi H\psi^{\dagger}) $. This gives $\frac{\partial \psi^{\dagger} \psi}{\partial t}= \frac{1}{i\hbar}((\psi^{\dagger}(v_{T}^{x}p_{x}+\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p})\psi-\psi (v_{T}^{x}p_{x}+\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p})\psi^{\dagger}))$ . This gives the current conservation equation, $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{j}$. This i understand to survive because particles are moving in crystal with fermi velocity.

Comment: In the relaxation time approximation the change in distribution function is $\delta f=e\tau(\vec{E}\cdot\vec{v})(-\frac{\partial f_{eq}(\varepsilon_{p})}{\partial \epsilon_{p}})$. The integral over the solid angle $\int\frac{d\Omega}{4\pi}$ of this distribution function is non-vanishing due to tilt velocity. This is $<\delta f>_{\Omega}=e\tau v_{T}^{x}E_{x}(-\frac{\partial f_{eq}(\varepsilon_{p})}{\partial \epsilon_{p}})$. I guess i am right.

Comment: The current operator is, as much as i remember, $\vec{j} = \nabla_\vec{p} H$, i.e. $\vec{j} = \vec{\sigma} + [v_T^x,0,0]$.  However, since your hamiltonian is translation-invariant, no density-fluctuation should be expected, i.e. $\nabla \cdot\langle\vec{j}\rangle = 0 = \partial_t\rho$.

Comment: @denklo , yes you are right. In second last comment, i only wanted to write the current equation. Probably i should not have said it survive. The point is Dirac particles are moving with fermi velocity and $v_{T}^{x}$, which i again missed to write in front of second term $v_{F}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}$. But there angle average projection should be zero in any particular direction like $\hat{x}$. In this case due to tilt velocity, this is not zero.